# React JS icons not showing

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, gulp-babel

I'm using [react-icons pack](https://github.com/gorangajic/react-icons) (only available for React) from GoranGajic.

If I import like `import * as IO from 'react-icons/io` I'm getting an error

*/Users/boris/WebstormProjects/autralis-sales-new/node_modules/react-icons/io/index.js:1
export IoAlertCircled from './alert-circled';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'*

If I import like `import * as IO from 'react-icons/lib/io` I'm not getting an error, but the icons are not showing. The div where `{IO.IoAndroidFavorite}` is, is empty.

**UPDATE**

I'm using ES6 and gulp/babel for transpiling. My .babelrc is as follows :

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Do you use ES6 in your project?

Comment: The transpilation step is not happening. Are you using Gulp / Babel, Browserify or Webpack to transpile?

Comment: Yes. I'm using ES6 in my project. And I'm using Gulp / Babel to transpile.

Comment: Have you tried changing your presets from ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"] to ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'] ?

Comment: @QoP Yes I am. The same problem.